# Load page in background

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, lazy-loading

is it possible to load web page in background using javascript/jquery? I mean load DOM, run all scripts, load all dependencies (CSS, external JS libraries). I don't want to load HTML and replace it. It's easy to do but will cause all styles/scripts to be loaded after replacement, not before (as far as I know).

The reason is that page loading time is 10-20s and I don't want page to freeze during loading content. There is single JS script which takes 2-4s to initialize. The idea is to show some placeholder page like "page is loading, please wait" and load everything in background.

I know page should be rebuilt so it doesn't take so much time to load but it's not possible in page owner's budget.

EDIT: I thought about loading page in iframe and then move iframe's content to the main body. Would it work? Wouldn't I loose some JS/Jquery data, pointers to DOM elements etc.? Wouldn't it cause to reload all JS?

Comment: Why not just show an overlay with the "page is loading", that is hidden/removed when the content is done loading?

Comment: Because client wants to see high score on google speed test... :) It's important to him for some reason, even if real page speed won't change.